# Маска ввода даты

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток!! вот 
[поле ввода даты](http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/7dhz3/) 
Как сделать так чтобы пользователь в дд мог вводить только число не больше 31 так как в месяце максимум 31 день в поле месяц 12 соответственно. Если кто владеет информацией или есть решение, буду очень признателен!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вариант регулярки:

```
/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0?(?:[1-9]|1[0-2]))\.[1-2][0-9]{3}$/
```

Но посмею заметить, что это далеко не самый лучший вариант — проверять дату регуляркой, как ты выразился, «по маске». Гораздо более правильным решением будет возложить валидацию на машину:

```
$(input).bind('keyup change', function()
    {
    var error = false;

    var value = $(this).val().split('.');
    if (value.length != 3 || !(value[0] && value[1] && value[2].length == 4))
        {
        error = 'Invalid value';
        }
    else
        {
        var date = new Date(value[2] + '-' + value[1] + '-' + value[0]);

        if (isNaN(date.getTime()))
            error = 'Invalid date';
        else if (parseInt(value[0]) != date.getDate())
            error = 'Unexpected day of month';
        else if (parseInt(value[1]) != date.getMonth() + 1)
            error = 'Unexpected month';
        else
            {
            var rValueYear = value[2].toString().split('').reverse().join('');
            var rDateYear = date.getFullYear().toString().split('').reverse().join('');
            if (rValueYear.length > rDateYear.length || rDateYear.indexOf(rValueYear) !== 0)
                error = 'Ambiguous year';
            }
        }

    if (error)
        {
        alert(error);
        //return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Врегулярных не силен, а вот скрипт что-то у меня не получаеться запустить его в моем примере((( не сочтите за наглость, не моглиб вы в моей песочнице показать как он работает. Спасибо!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7dhz3/1/

А вот вариант с регуляркой: http://jsfiddle.net/7dhz3/2/
Но он позволяет вводить, скажем "31.02.2014". Поэтому-то предыдущий вариант и лучше

Comment: Все гуд, огромное спасибо!!

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" id="txtlimit">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#txtlimit').on('keyup', function(){
  var numlimit = 31;
    if(this.value>numlimit){
        this.value=oldvalue;
        alert('Wrong number!');
    }else{
      oldvalue=this.value;
    }
});
```

});

Comment: не совсем то что мне нужно, мне нужно проверять чтобы дни не превышали 31, месяцы 12, но они могут быть так же начинаться с 0 к примеру 05.05.2014

Comment: Ага и год таким образом можно задать 123456789